# skaffold/kaniko: Get access to service from another namespace

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold, kaniko

I've deployed a registry service into a namespace `registry`:

```
$ kubectl get service -n registry
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
registry-docker-registry   ClusterIP   10.43.119.11   <none>        5000/TCP   18h
```

this is my `skaffold.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta1
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: spring-boot-slab
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: skaffold-covid-backend
    kaniko:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-multistage
      cache: {}
  cluster: {}
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s/*
```

Everything works fine, up to when kaniko is trying to push the image to above registry:

> Get "http://registry-docker-registry.registry.svc.cluster.local:5000/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-docker-registry.registry.svc.cluster.local on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

Any ideas about how to get access to this registry deployed inside the same kubernetes?

I've tried to get access to the registry from another pod:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti graylog-1 -- curl registry-docker-registry.registry:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["skaffold-covid-backend","skaffold-covid-backend/cache"]}
```

As you can see, it's able to get access to registry.

Comment: add content of /etc/resolv.conf file from the pod from which you are doing lookup. and add output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: for some reason its not going through core dns name server

Answer (score 0):

According to this [instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns), you can get access to:

```
registry-docker-registry.registry
```

or according to the [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/):

```
registry-docker-registry.registry.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to `exec` a pod in your intended namespace and try to curl the service that you want to reach as well as its port. The format in general is:

```
<your-service>.<your-namespace>
```

So from your intended pod you can curl it using the following [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns):

```
curl <your-service>.<your-namespace>:<your-port>
```

2. Try to `port forward` your service to your local using the following command:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> svc/<your-service> <your-localhost-port>:<your-service-port>
```

See whether you can access it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I hope this command will work.

```
registry-docker-registry.registry.svc.cluster.local
```